# Enviar repositório local para repositório remoto

Tags: bitbucket

Olá.

Quero mandar meu projeto chamado de sfp para o bitbucket.

Não criei este projeto ou repositório lá no bit, mas quero saber se é possível já mandar e criar o repo ao mesmo tempo.

Por exemplo: eu digito o comando mais ou menos assim:

git remote add sfp git:/bitbucket.org/andre_sn/sfp.git

E já criar o repositório. Daí é só eu fazer o push. Não estou conseguindo, como procedo?

Comment: pelo que sei tens de fazer o commit antes de fazer o push. depois vai ao bitbucket e fazes tbm commit no teu repositorio....antes de um commit deves fazes push sempre.

Comment: para eu comittar preciso ter o repositório criado do mesmo jeito. Então chegamos a conclusão que não há como criar um repositório pelo terminal ou interface gráfica, só pela página.

Comment: Há uma ferramenta para criar repos pela linha de comando https://hub.github.com/ porém suporta apenas o Github. Uma boa explicação de como usar http://blog.caelum.com.br/github-na-linha-de-comando/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sendo bem simples existem, algumas maneiras de publicar seu projeto no bitbucket, certo de que você já baixou a ferramenta git Bash( linha de codigo ) e Git GUI (Interface gráfica), uma maneira bem simples é seguir essa sequencia aqui no git bash, você é obrigado a ter um repositório criado no bit.

```
// Va na pasta do projeto e inicie o git
git init

// Diga para o git o caminho do seu acesso remoto
git remote add origin https://dfps@bitbucket.org/dfps/teste-novo.git


//Crie seu primeiro arquivo, faça commit e push 
echo "Diego Santos" >> texto.txt

git add texto.txt
git commit -m 'Comentarios a respeito do arquivo'

// Aqui ele faz a magica de jogar pra bitbucket
git push -u origin master
```

Se precisar de maiores detalhes é so pedir!

Comment: e para adicionar todos os arquivos, é git add .?